# Upload image using multer to Firebase Storage issue

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, multer

Hello I am trying to upload an image using Node.js/multer to firebase storage (note: I know I can do it client side but this needs to work server side). I am running into this issue:

> TypeError: storage.ref is not a function

I tried solving by adding `import 'firebase/storage';` as other Stack Overflows have suggested but that did not work.

Router:

```
import {FirebaseManager, FirebaseReferences} from '../database_manager';

router.post("/:uuid/image", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
    const tempPath = req.file.path;
    const ext = path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase();

    if (ext === ".png" || ext === ".jpg") {
        FirebaseManager.upload_image(FirebaseReferences.Images, 'test', req.file)
        res.status(200).contentType("text/plain").end("File uploaded!");
    } else {
        try {
            fs.unlinkSync(tempPath);
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).send(err.message);
        }
        res.status(403).contentType("text/plain").end("Only .png/jpg files are allowed!");
    }
  }
);
```

Firebase Manager:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
import firebase = require('firebase/app');
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/storage';

// Access the real-time database in the initialized application.
const FirebaseApp: firebase.app.App = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: '',
    clientEmail: '',
    privateKey: ''
  }),
  databaseURL: 'https://.firebaseio.com'
});
const db: firebase.database.Database = FirebaseApp.database();
const storage: firebase.storage.Storage = FirebaseApp.storage();

export function upload_image(ref: FirebaseReferences, filename: string,
        file: any): string {

        var upload_loc = ref.toString() + '/' + filename;
        var upload_ref = storage.ref().child(upload_loc);

        upload_ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
                console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
                return downloadURL;
            });
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("FirebaseManager, upload_image(): " + error);
            throw error;
        });

        return 'error';
}
```

Also will uploading a `Express.Multer.File` type to Storage work? If not how can I convert that type to a type of `File`?

```
node 10.2.1
multer 1.4.1
firebase ^5.7.3
firebase-admin ^6.5.0
```

Comment: Looks like it can't find `ref` on your storage object in your upload_image function. I'm not entirely certain if you need to call bucket first. Additionally, I've experienced some issues in the past with express and code defined outside of exported functions. Could you, instead of calling `storage.ref()` in your upload_image function try calling `admin.storage().bucket().ref()` instead?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing `storageBucket` in the config for `admin.initializeApp`

```
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com"
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start