# Passing files from react-dropzone to express server

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm currently trying to send my files to my express server but every time I try and send my request the body is empty. After some research, it seems like they would not be stored in req.body so I'm not sure how to actually access the files that I've stored in my formdata.

Clientside code

```
export default async function UploadToFireStorage(accepetedfiles,fileVals){//Index are 1-1

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('files', accepetedfiles);

  try{

    const response = await fetch(`https://someUrl`,{
      method:"POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    })

    const jsonData = await response.json()

    console.log(jsonData) //Attempt to see how my req is formed

  }catch(error){

      console.log(error)

  }

}
```

express code

```
app.post('/uploadNewFiles',async(req,res)=>{

try{

    const files = req.? // im not sure what to access after sending my formdata

    for(let file = 0;file < files.length;file++){

        let storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${files[file].path}`);
        let uploadTask = await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, files[file]);

    }

    res.json(files)

}catch(error){

    res.json('Error: ' + error)

}

})
```

So just to clarify my question. I know when I make a fetch request I can package data that needs to be sent so I can post it and then extract it using something like `let someVar = req.body.someVar` and I've tried that with my file array but am unable to get my file array back and i'm not totally sure how to access it from req.

Answer (score 1):

To properly post the files, don't use `JSON.stringify`. Set the `body` equal to `formData` directly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46640744/6322589) for more detail.

On the server side, you'll need to use a body parser that can handle multi-part form data, like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) . See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631882/6322589) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks I'll go ahead and look into this.

Comment: I believe the first bit worked but I know multer doesn't work well with firebase so I'll keep looking for something to handle it.

Comment: @boredProjects I haven't personally worked with firebase before, but it seems like multer should work with it just fine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600971/upload-image-using-multer-to-firebase-storage-issue

Comment: I don't believe it does as this is still an issue on github https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/141. Also, I've attempted myself and the req.body etc is always empty due to firebase doing their own preprocessing.